# How to sort on a numeric column in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

(Looked at a bunch of answers on this topic, none of which applies to this question.)

The DataTables have the feature of letting the user click on each column's Up/Down triangle icons to sort in Ascending or Descending order.  I have loaded the data as follows

```
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","1,541,512","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","3,541,512","2.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","541,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","2,541,512","32.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","741,512","3.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["A Bogus data","41,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","2,541,512","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Z Bogus data","1,541,512","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","3,541,512","2.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["La Bogus data","541,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["The Bogus data","2,541,512","32.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","741,512","3.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","41,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","2,541,512","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","1,541,512","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","3,541,512","2.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","541,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","2,541,512","32.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","741,512","3.5%","0","0","0"]);
        oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","41,512","1.5%","0","0","0"]);
```

In column number 2 the numeric values are processed alphabetically when I click on the Up/Down triangles.  How can I adjust it so that the second column Up/Down arrows will trigger the proper way, treating the characters as numbers.  I tried using the following initialization:

```
oTable = $('.utable').dataTable( {
"aoColumns": [{ sWidth: '60%' },{sWidth: '30%', "sType": "numeric"},{ sWidth: '10%' }],
"sDom": 'rt',
"sScrollY":"200px",
"bPaginate":false,
"bFilter":false,
"bInfo": false});
```

All this does is to lock the colum and the Up/Down icons will not work in the header of that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the numbers are not being recognized as such and even if they were, the commas in your numbers would probably the sorting function off (because it will probably not properly remove them).

One option you have is to implement your own sorting function which deals with your numbers properly. Here's an example that does what you need:

http://live.datatables.net/oborug/2/edit

PS -- Here's the relevant documentation: http://datatables.net/development/sorting

Comment: Pete, you rascal.  You understood the problem perfectly!  You rock, dude!!  Thank you...  It worked right off the bat!  This remains for me to comb carefully.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, dude.  I have been busting my head for a couple days on and off without success.  This solution is adroit as an answer could be!

Comment: This looks great - but I must be missing something, maybe just looking at it wrong - when I go to that example from the posted link it behaves exactly as advertised, but I can't for the life of me see the custom sorting code, or how it may have been included - is this functionality already in the nightly build perhaps? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

Technically column number two contains strings (1,000) - numbers with a comma and so does column 3 - numbers with percentages). Best thing for you to do is to pass the data to data tables as an integer (without commas and %) and write a custom formatter to add commas and percentages using **mRender** option  (read about it at **http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns**).

If you add custom formatting to your data also do not forget to set the option to use underlying data as your sort source rather than the displayed data.

Comment: You said, "...do not forget to set the option to use underlying data as your sort source rather than the displayed data."  How do I make sure of that?

Comment: In the older version of datatables you would use bUseRendered=false but that option is now deprecated - have a good read of mData/mRender docs for an alternative. But ultimately it will be some option that you must set

Comment: Reading furiously... err earnestly...!

Comment: There is too little information on how to use mRender.  The two examples given are using Ajax and I cannot weed through it.  And the author of the Datatables simply did not document that option carefully enough.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as DKean. I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript. Can someone please post the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a function of sorting ( try to use sort by selection or sort by insertion ) try to stock your data variables in an array and do the caculations , else you can do the sort directly with your data

Comment: What I need to do is find where their sorting function lies and replace it.  Can you help me find it, else the sorting will not be dynamic.  The user needs to have the power to sort by every column just the way it is set right now.  I cannot lose the functionality of the little triangles in the header columns

Answer (score 0):

Hello I made this using `parseFloat` and replace methods and using this example http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["string-nbr-asc"]  = function(x,y) {return ((parseFloat(x.replace(",","")) < parseFloat(y.replace(",",""))) ? -1 : ((parseFloat(x.replace(",","")) > parseFloat(y.replace(",",""))) ?  1 : 0));};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["string-nbr-desc"] = function(x,y) {return ((parseFloat(x.replace(",","")) < parseFloat(y.replace(",",""))) ?  1 : ((parseFloat(x.replace(",","")) > parseFloat(y.replace(",",""))) ? -1 : 0));};
```

If you have 10 columns and want to `sort` `7,8,9` wich are numbers like `7,081 1,925.49` use

```
"aoColumns":[null,null,null,null,null,null,{ "sType": "string-nbr" },{ "sType": "string-nbr" },{ "sType": "string-nbr" },null]
```